# How to increase login sessions timeout in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, logging

I currently have the following configuration for session lifetime in my Laravel application:

```php
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

How can I extend my user login session to 30 days? Currently, the session lifetime is set to 120 minutes with 'expire_on_close' set to false. What changes should I make in the provided Laravel configuration to achieve this?"

Comment: Do you have a `SESSION_LIFETIME` set in you `.env` file?

Comment: If 120 minutes is equal 1/365 month units, what should be set there to have "month" value there?

Comment: Did you try simply `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 60 * 24 * 30),`

Comment: Why would you want the session to last that long?  You should use "remember me" so that the session can be cleared down. If you don't then I hope you don't have many unique users/  The answer is simple, in .env set the SESSION_LIFETIME=43200

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, there is no SESSION_LIFETIME in .env

Comment: Yes I just did the same @Snapey thanks man.

Comment: If there is no SESSION_LIFETIME in the .env file, then add it!